# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles. No definition for GetFiles?

Tags: c#

I wrote some code to get the files in a directory. In order to do this I used the Directory.GetFiles method. I've used it before, so I know it exists and works.

So I started using it (I'm using the System.IO namespace) and it tells me that 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'GetFiles'. Indeed, if I use the intellisense, there is no such method. [MSDN tells me that there is though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx), and I know I've used it before, and I'm 99% sure it was System.IO.Directory.

I do have System.IO.Directory... it just doesn't have that method. It has methods like 'GetCreationTime', 'GetDirectoryRoot', 'GetLastAccessTime', 'SetCurrentDirectory' and so on, but no 'GetFiles'.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: *How* are you using the method?

Comment: You're not targeting .Net 1.1 by accident are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you making the call? That will tell us a lot about why the compiler might be complaining.

There are [3 Overloads for GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx) on [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa70yfe2.aspx)

Could you be looking for [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx)

> Indeed, if I use the intellisense, there is no such method

**The only 2 logical things I can think of that might cause this:**

1. Visual Studio, or your solution are in a corrupted state (Restart VS / Reboot)
2. Your Project is targeting a version of .Net lower than 2.0 *(`GetFiles` was introduced in 2.0)*

Comment: I must thank you for your time, but I did something stupid, and in my frustration I could not see it.

You see, I copied this from another project I'd been working on. Why did it work in one and not the other? Were there different references? Yes, but the main difference is that my new project is a Silverlight client which, of course, does not have the same access levels to the machine as a regular C# application.

Sorry if I wasted your time, but perhaps one day someone else will come and see this and it will help them.

Answer (score 0):

If you focus this issue using the framework of `Silverlight 4` just change the use of `.Getfiles(string directory)` into `.EnumerateFiles(string directory)` instead