# System.IO.Path does not contain a definition for GetFiles

Tags: c#, string, file, text-files, .net

I have a weird error. I got a text file with 2 lines. 1 with a directory path and 1 for data.

The application writes all the paths of the files in the given directory to a text file. But I want to be able to change the path, via a second text file.

Here's the code for reading the text file:

```
//Reads 2 lines of the text file
string[] TextData = File.ReadAllLines(@text file);
    string DirectoryPath = TextData[1];
    string ScanHours = TextData[2];
```

And here's the code for writing all the files that `string DirectoryPath = TextData[1];` finds:

```
//Writes all the files of DirectoryPath into a string
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Basicly, `string DirectoryPath = TextData[1];` refers to a line in the text file. The line contains a path to a directory.

I get this error: `System.IO.Directory does not contain a definition for GetFiles`.
I tried multiple things, for example changing the `Directory.GetFileS();` to `Path.GetFiles();`

If anyone can help me, or point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it! :)

**EDIT -> The complete code**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] TextData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TextData.txt");
            string DirectoryPath = TextData[1];
            //string ScanHours = TextData[2];

        //Original
        //string DirectoryPath = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\DirectoryPath.txt");

        string[] files = Path.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> updatedFiles = new List<string>();

        DateTime from = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        DateTime to = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (string name in files)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(name);
            string fullname = file.FullName;

            if (file.LastWriteTime >= from && file.LastWriteTime <= to)
            {
                updatedFiles.Add(name);

                Console.WriteLine(file.FullName + " ; " + "last changed at >>  " + " ; " + file.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

There was a FileStream/Streamwriter in there to log every output. But I removed it.

**EDIT 2 -> When using `Directory.GetFiles` instead of `Path.GetFiles`**

System.ArgumentException: The path has an invalid format.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)

at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)

at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)

at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)

at CheckWithinTime.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Vvandereng\Documents\Stage\Programmeren\LastWriteAccess-Checker\LastWriteAccess-Checker\Program.cs:regel 30

Comment: Are you sure that `Directory` is `System.IO.Directory`?

Comment: Looking at error I think you have your own  class named `System.IO.Directory`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - more likely in the local namespace.

Comment: Use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(...)` to be sure to use the correct class. Also you are using lines 2 and 3 from your input file. Verify by logging the results.

Comment: The program used to get files directly from a path. Back then everything worked. But as soon as I changed it to get the data out of a text file, I got this error. I think that the `Directory error` was because that it was linked to the original. But now I don't know what to replace it with.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Nope, If it were in local namespace error would be like `MyNamespace.Directory` does not contain a definition for GetFiles. but error clearly says `System.IO.Directory` does not contain a definition for GetFiles. I assume op have a class `Directory` in namespace `System.IO`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - you're right.

Comment: Vacomaker, what platform is this?  Phone or SilverLight? Win 8 Store?

Comment: It's Windows 7, and it's not in a class. I've added a quick summary to my question, maybe it'll help?

Comment: No, your edit is not helping. Post some code to reproduce

Comment: Could it be any of the stuff mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637757/system-io-directory-getfiles-no-definition-for-getfiles?rq=1

Comment: Will it be any help if I post the full code? Well, most of the relevant parts.

Comment: It would be a big help if you created a small but complete (Console) App that reproduces the problem. Verify before posting.

Comment: What does this return: `Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Directory)).CodeBase);`

Comment: Ok this not answer your question, but to get files you can try with `var Directory = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryPath);` and then `Directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`.

Comment: I've put a compact version of my code in the question.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria that was in fact part of the original code. But as I explained is that I want to permamently use 1 directory. That's why there is a text file to change it.

Comment: @vascomakker As a side note, the variable names that start with uppercase can bring a bit of confusion at least in c# for its standard naming convention (see this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497103/what-are-the-naming-conventions-in-c).

Comment: I added the error I get with `Directory.GetFiles`. Right now I'm working mobile, so no Visual Studio so the error looks a little different then normal.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what do you mean by `Also you are using lines 2 and 3 from your input file`?

Comment: The first line is in `TextData[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this error: System.IO.Directory does not contain a definition for GetFiles

This is confusing, here error shows

> Error 1 'System.IO.Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetFiles'

Try the following with `Directory.GetFiles`

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: I see what you're going for. But that's the exact code which I started with, nothing has changed.

Comment: Your code uses `Path.GetFiles`. If `Directory.GetFiles` also causing the same error post code using that and the complete error message rather than saying same error message. Surely error message will differ, that will help us to solve the problem

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right, sorry. I added the error I get when using `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: `DirectoryPath` variable has invalid arguments or it is not a valid path. Check that. It should solve the problem

Comment: I double checked it, and everything is linked correctly. I don't wanna sound rude or anything, I appreciate the help! But I think that it got something to do with `string[] TextData`.

Comment: Is it? post what is the value you get in `DirectoryPath` variable

Comment: `local variable string DirectoryPath` but this is normal right?

Comment: `DirectoryPath`'s value? What was the value of `DirectoryPath` at the time of exception?

Comment: Well, what you just sudgested is something I've never tried before ^^. Other strings have paths `"C:\etc"`, but `DirectoryPath` has nothing, just `""`. So maybe you were right haha, I'll look into this.

Comment: I've edited my code with a `StreamReader`. Now it is working smoothly as planned. Thanks for all the suggestions :D

Answer (score -3):

Try removing line end characters from the DirectoryPath value.